# Error al iniciar sesión en mi aplicación genexus

Tags: java, genexus, compilador, war

Estoy intentando subir un compilado a mi servidor (Estoy usando dailyrazor como hosting), cuando lo subo subo un war, hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es que al hacer login (ingresar mis credenciales) me genera el siguiente error: **com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: com.genexus.servlet.ServletException: com.genexus.util.Encryption$InvalidGXKeyException: Invalid key**

¿A alguien le ha pasado?

Comment: Pareceria un problema con la key de encriptación de datos de conexión a la base, sesiones, etc. Revisaría este documento a ver si es el caso: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?36909,Application+Encryption+Key+property#Considerations

Comment: Muchas gracias, con eso solucione